# Some words missing from comments in .odt file made in win8 and opened in ubuntu, via LibreOffice(in both)

Tags: 14.04, windows-8, libreoffice, bug-reporting, odt

I had saved a `.odt` file in my windows 8.1, in which I had saved credentials associated with each and every website I had account on. When I opened that file in ubuntu its email/username and in few cases passwords are also missing!
Note that I saved username and password in comments in `.odt` file. Also, in both windows 8.1 and ubuntu, I used LibreOffice Writer to make/use/edit the file. Now I had removed the windows 8.1 and installed ubuntu instead. Why does that happen? How can I recover the email/user(which are different for different websites and too many) in ubuntu?

An example of what I saved in windows 8.1 and what I get in ubuntu(14.04 LTS):

**As saved in Windows:**

> Username: abc@gmail.com
>
> Password: abcdxyz

**As I get in Ubuntu:**

> Username:
>
> Password: abcdxyz

In some cases I wrote multiple username/email and passwords in a single comment and in that cases passwords are also missing(only in few). Please help me recover those missing words in ubuntu!

Comment: Please add the versions of Libreoffice you used. It is more probable that the difference in Libreoffice versions is important, than the difference in OSs. Moreover, are you sure the comments are gone and not just not printable due to missing fonts? Don't save the file on exit. Try your experiments on a copy

Comment: @Bruni :  I don't know the version I used in windows, but on ubuntu its 4.2.8.2 . And I'm sure the missing words in the comments are gone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Unzip the .odt file to a folder.
2. Open `content.xml` in a web browser.
3. Start at `<office:body>` and look for comments, probably in `office:annotation` tags.

Is the data there?  If so, then move the usernames and passwords to a [better place](http://lifehacker.com/5529133/five-best-password-managers).  Especially I would not rely on comments for such valuable information.

If not, then the data is no longer in the document, and must have been deleted earlier.

Comment: Just want to add to that list my personal favorit keepassX

Comment: I unzip the file and then opened content.xml in web browser and the missing contents are still not there! I also installed the LibreOffice on another laptop(my brother's) with windows 8.1 with the current version 5.x.x, and all missing content showed up! Also, thanks for telling the alternatives of saving credentials...:)